# Confusion with React Native Navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm building a React Native gig guide app, using stack navigation to get around the different screens.

So here's what I want to happen - the user can navigate from `Map.js` to `List.js`, where they're presented with a list of gigs. I want them to be able to tap on a gig and be directed to `GigDetails.js`, where they can see the details about that specific gig. 

Users also have the option of tapping on a gig marker in `Map.js` which also directs them to `GigDetails.js`. How do I configure my routing so users can get to `GigDetails` from **both**  `Map.js` and `List.js`?

Currently, Map-to-details is working, but I don't know how to go from List-to-details.

App structure is as follows (route with asterisk is the part I'm having trouble with:

```
screens/List.js  <-----> screens/Map.js (Home screen)
          *|                  |
          *|                  | (GigDetails navigated to via map Marker Callout)
          *|                  |
       *GigDetails.js         GigDetails.js
```

Code:

**App.js**

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { MyStack } from './routes/homeStack';

export default function App() {

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MyStack/>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

**HomeStack.js**

```
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import List from '../screens/List'
import Map from '../screens/Map'
import Header from "../components/Header";
import GigDetails from "../screens/GigDetails";

const Stack = createStackNavigator()

export const MyStack = () => {

  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Map"
    >
      <Stack.Screen 
      name="Map" 
      component={Map} 
      options={{
        headerTitle: () => <Header/>,
        headerTitleAlign: 'center'
    }}     
      />
      <Stack.Screen 
      name="List" 
      component={List} 
      options={{
        headerTitle: () => <Header/>,
        headerTitleAlign: 'center'
    }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen 
      name="GigDetails" 
      component={GigDetails} 
      options={{
        headerTitle: () => <Header/>,
        headerTitleAlign: 'center'
    }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

**Map.js**

```
import { StyleSheet,View,Text,Pressable } from 'react-native'
import GigMap from '../components/GigMap'

const Map = ({ navigation }) => {
    return (
        <View style = {styles.container}>
            <GigMap navigation = {navigation}/>
            <View style = {styles.footer}>
            <Pressable
                title = "Go to list view"
                onPress = {() => navigation.navigate("List")}
                style = {styles.button}
            >
                <Text style = {styles.buttonText}>List View</Text>
            </Pressable>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

**GigMap.js**

```
import { useState,useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,Pressable } from 'react-native';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
import { Marker,Callout } from 'react-native-maps';
import { query,collection,getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { db } from '../firebase';
import CalloutView from './CalloutView';
import { mapStyle } from '../util/mapStyle';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';



const GigMap = ({ navigation }) => {

  
  const [gigs, setGigs] = useState([]);
  const [ date,setDate ] = useState(dateToday)
  const [ daysAdded,setDaysAdded ] = useState(1)

  //Generating current date
  
  const addHours =(numOfHours, date = new Date()) => {
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + numOfHours * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    return date;
  }
  
  let localDate = addHours(13)

  useEffect(() => {
    setDate(localDate)
  },[])
  
  const addDay = () => {
    setDaysAdded(daysAdded+1)
    localDate.setDate(localDate.getDate() + daysAdded)
    setDate(localDate)
  }

  console.log(date)
  
  const day = new Date().getDate();
  const month = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
  const year = new Date().getFullYear();
  const dateToday = `${day}/${month}/${year}`;




  //Making call to Firebase to retrieve gig documents from 'gigs' collection
  useEffect(() => {
    const getGigs = async () => {
      try {
        const gigArray = [];
        const q = query(collection(db, "gigs"));
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) =>
          gigArray.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() })
        );
        setGigs(gigArray);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(`Error: ${err}`);
      }
    };
    getGigs();
  }, []);

  //Filtering through gigs to return only current day's gigs
  const gigsToday = gigs.filter((gig) => gig.date === dateToday);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.headerText}>Today's gigs</Text>
      <MapView
        initialRegion={{
          latitude: -41.29416,
          longitude: 174.77782,
          latitudeDelta: 0.03,
          longitudeDelta: 0.03,
        }}
        style={styles.map}
        customMapStyle={mapStyle}
      >
        {gigsToday.map((gig, i) => (
          <Marker
            key={i}
            coordinate={{
              latitude: gig.location.latitude,
              longitude: gig.location.longitude,
            }}
            image={require("../assets/Icon_Gold_48x48.png")}
          >
            <Callout
              style={styles.callout}
              onPress={() =>
                navigation.navigate("GigDetails", {
                  venue: gig.venue,
                  date: gig.date,
                  gigName: gig.gigName,
                  time: gig.time,
                })
              }
            >
              <CalloutView
                venue={gig.venue}
                date={gig.date}
                gigName={gig.gigName}
                time={gig.time}
                style={styles.calloutView}
              />
            </Callout>
          </Marker>
        ))}
      </MapView>
      <View style = {styles.buttonOptions}>
      <Pressable >
        <Text style = {styles.buttonOptionsText}>previous day's gigs</Text>
      </Pressable>
      <Pressable onPress = {addDay}>
        <Text style = {styles.buttonOptionsText}>next day's gigs</Text>
      </Pressable>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

**List.js**

```
import { View,Text } from 'react-native'
import ListByDay from '../components/ListByDay';

const List = () => {
    return (
        <View>
            <ListByDay/>
        </View>
    )
}
 
export default List;
```

**ListByDay.js**

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,FlatList,TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { useGigs } from '../hooks/useGigs';

const ListByDay = ({ navigation }) => {

    const gigs = useGigs()

    return ( 
        <View>
            <Text style = {styles.header}>Gigs today</Text>
            <FlatList
                data = {gigs}
                renderItem = {({ item }) => (
                    <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.test}>
                        <Text>{item.venue}</Text>
                        <Text>{item.gigName}</Text>
                        <Text>{item.date}</Text>
                        <Text>{item.time}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                )}
            />
        </View>
     );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    test: {
        borderWidth:1,
        borderColor:'black',
    },
    header: {
        padding:10
    }
})


 
export default ListByDay;
```

Comment: Im pretty sure you can just navigate to it normally since they are in the same stack. The stack will push the new component (GigDetails) on top of either Map.js or List.js.

Comment: You need to share `ListByDay`. Most likely you have a flatlist of gigs there. You can navigate on press to the details as you did for maps.

Comment: @DavidScholz have just added it. I tried what you suggested but it didn't work unforutnately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The component `ListByDay` currently tries to destructure the `navigation` object from its props. However, the `navigation` object is passed by the react-navigation framework to the components that are defined as screens inside a `navigator`. This is not the case for `ListByDay`. Thus, you cannot access the `navigation` object as you are currently trying to do.

There are multiple options.

**1) Pass the navigation object as a prop from its parent which is a screen inside a navigator**

Since `List` is the parent component for `ListByDay` and `List` is an actual screen defined in your stack navigator, it will receive the `navigation` object as a prop from the react-navigation framework. You can access it and pass it to its children.

```js
const List = ({navigation}) => {
    return (
        <View>
            <ListByDay navigation={navigation} />
        </View>
    )
}
```

Then, implement the navigation logic in the `onPress` function of your `TouchableOpacity` inside `ListByDay`.

```js
const ListByDay = ({ navigation }) => {

    const gigs = useGigs()

    return ( 
        <View>
            <Text style = {styles.header}>Gigs today</Text>
            <FlatList
                data = {gigs}
                renderItem = {({ item }) => (
                    <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.test} onPress={() => navigation.navigate(...)}>
                        <Text>{item.venue}</Text>
                        <Text>{item.gigName}</Text>
                        <Text>{item.date}</Text>
                        <Text>{item.time}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                )}
            />
        </View>
     );
}
```

**2) Use the useNavigation hook**

If you do not want to pass the navigation object down to `ListByDay`, then you can always use the `useNavigation` hook instead.

```js
const ListByDay = () => {
    const navigation = useNavigation()
    const gigs = useGigs()

    return ( 
        <View>
            <Text style = {styles.header}>Gigs today</Text>
            <FlatList
                data = {gigs}
                renderItem = {({ item }) => (
                    <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.test} onPress={() => navigation.navigate(...)}>
                        <Text>{item.venue}</Text>
                        <Text>{item.gigName}</Text>
                        <Text>{item.date}</Text>
                        <Text>{item.time}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                )}
            />
        </View>
     );
}
```